# Tables declared WITH OIDS are not supported

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

This error occurs when I run the PG installcheck of AGE:

```
cd ~/new-age/age
make PG_CONFIG=~/age_project/postgres/bin/pg_config installcheck
```

Output:

```
/home/marcos/age_project/postgres/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/../../src/test/regress/pg_regress --inputdir=./ --bindir='/home/marcos/age_project/postgres/bin'    --load-extension=age --inputdir=.//regress --outputdir=.//regress --temp-instance=.//regress/instance --port=61958 --encoding=UTF-8 --dbname=contrib_regression scan graphid agtype catalog cypher expr cypher_create cypher_match cypher_unwind cypher_set cypher_remove cypher_delete cypher_with cypher_vle cypher_union cypher_call cypher_merge age_global_graph age_load index analyze graph_generation name_validation drop
============== removing existing temp instance        ==============
============== creating temporary instance            ==============
============== initializing database system           ==============
============== starting postmaster                    ==============
running on port 61958 with PID 132693
============== creating database "contrib_regression" ==============
CREATE DATABASE
ALTER DATABASE
============== installing age                         ==============
ERROR:  tables declared WITH OIDS are not supported
command failed: "/home/marcos/age_project/postgres/bin/psql" -X -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"age\"" "contrib_regression"
make: *** [/home/marcos/age_project/postgres/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk:420: installcheck] Error 2
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Apache AGE branch is compatible with the PostgreSQL version, and that you have used `git fetch` and `git pulled` so you can be up-to-date with everything.

You can follow the Apache AGE [official guide](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/setup.html) and you will not have any problem!

Answer (score 0):

`WITH OIDS` was supported in the older versions of PostgreSQL and its purpose was to generate object IDs.

It is not supported by the new versions of PostgreSQL which are compatible with AGE. So, you have to use the PostgreSQL **compatible version (PG11,12,13)** with AGE.